# ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__catboost)

Tags: python, module, catboost

I am getting the following error:

```
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__catboost)
```

I used

> "`"../../../ya" make -r -DUSE_ARCADIA_CUDA_HOST_COMPILER=no --host-platform-flag USE_ARCADIA_CUDA_HOST_COMPILER=no -DUSE_ARCADIA_PYTHON=yes -DOS_SDK=local -DPY3/THON_INCLUDEda="/ envs/python3.6/include" -DPYTHON_LIBRARIES="D:/anaconda3/envs/python3.6/libs/python3.lib" -DCUDA_ROOT="C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.1/ "-o="D:_catboost.pyd\catboost/python-package/catboost" -k"`

to generate the`_catboost.pyd` file. I replaced the`_catboost.pyd` file in the catboost package with it and I used `import catboost` in Jupyter, but there was such an error. I can't find the reason these days.

Full error message:

```
ImportError Traceback (most recent call last)
in
----> 1 import catboost
2 from catboost import *
3 import shap
4 import pandas as pd
5 from shap import plots

D:\anaconda3\envs\python3.6\lib\site-packages\catboost_init_.py in
----> 1 from .core import (
2 FeaturesData, EFstrType, EShapCalcType, EFeaturesSelectionAlgorithm, Pool, CatBoost,
3 CatBoostClassifier, CatBoostRegressor, CatBoostError, cv, train, sum_models, _have_equal_features,
4 to_regressor, to_classifier, MultiRegressionCustomMetric, MultiRegressionCustomObjective
5 ) # noqa

D:\anaconda3\envs\python3.6\lib\site-packages\catboost\core.py in
40 _typeof = type
41
---> 42 from .plot_helpers import save_plot_file, try_plot_offline
43 from . import _catboost
44

D:\anaconda3\envs\python3.6\lib\site-packages\catboost\plot_helpers.py in
1 import warnings
2
----> 3 from . import _catboost
4 fspath = _catboost.fspath
5
    
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__catboost)
```

```
catboost version:0.25.1
Operating System:win10
```